# How to make a compile time error if an enum variant is passed to a function

Tags: enums, rust

Suppose I have an `enum`:

```
enum Foobar {
    Foo(i32),
    Bar(f64)
}
```

I also have a function that takes a `Foobar` as an argument:

```
fn foo(x: &mut Foobar) {
    match x {
        Foobar::Foo(i32) => { /* do something */ },
        Foobar::Bar(f64) => { /* panic */ }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to throw a compile time error if the caller of the function passes the `Bar` variant to the function, without using a compiler plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Even a compiler plugin (by which I assume you mean a "lint") can't possibly cover all cases.

If you want to make it statically impossible to pass a particular piece of data to the function, then change the types so that it's *actually* not valid: define a sibling of `Foobar` that doesn't have the `Bar` variant, along with some conversions between the two.

There is no simple or automatic way to do this in Rust; you'll just have to do the hard yakka.  Or wait for refinement types, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: In this case I can simply do nothing or panic, as I am the only user of the function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @pengowen123 if you are the only user of the function, you can Make Foo and Bar two separate structs and define an enum for when you want to accept either of them, like this [example](http://is.gd/ayeZaS)

Comment: I am using an `enum` to store a vector of slightly different types. Is it possible to do something like in your example but as a method on the `enum`?

Comment: @pengowen123 If you want to reply to someone you should mention their name at the start, or they might never know.  I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for here, but I don't think so.  A `Vec` can only have *one* element type, which would presumably be the enum, and the enum cannot assume one variant or the other isn't being used.